# How to know the default value of Windows group policies?

Tags: windows, group-policy

In Windows group policy, all settings are shown as "Not configured" initially, but there must be a default value even if you didn't set it, how to make it show the current default settings?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question, with a multi-faceted answer.

First of all, you can typically find the answer within the narrative that accompanies the `Help` section associated with each group policy.  They will usually emphasize what you can expect to see if *"If you do not configure this setting,"* or perhaps what might happen *"If you disable or do not configure it."*  Either way, the anticipated behavior is described for our benefit.

Last but not least, for many years Microsoft has made a spreadsheet available that is a free download titled the **Group Policy Settings Reference**.  Of course you can search and filter within this ".xlsx" document, and in addition to including the `Help` text that I referenced above it also features a `Registry Information` column that you can use to cross-reference the current settings within the operating system:

[Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250)